# One of the nodes of a 4 node cluster is not allowing me to access GFS

Tags: linux, gfs

[root@host3 ~]# cd /var/opt/new/new1/global
-bash: cd: /var/opt/new/new1/global: Input/output error

output of the df :

/dev/mapper/vgglobal-lvol3
                      11524928   2560092   8964836  23% /var/opt/new/new1/global

One of the nodes , doesn't allow me to CD to this GFS file system !!! I cant understand whats happening . The bash itself is telling me i/o error !

Answer (score 0):

```
cman_tool status
```

I would assume your local node has faulted and is fenced out.  Once you figure out why it is fenced, resolve that, you should be able to rejoin the cluster.